# Jboss RestEasy Oauth2

Tags: java, security, jboss, oauth-2.0, resteasy

I want develop REST service with oauth2 security. I selected JBOSS Stack technology **JBOSS.8(wildfly)+RestEasy.3.0.5**. In `RestEasy` guide i founded how to enable oauth module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-yaml-provider" services="import"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi" services="import"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" services="import"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.skeleton-key"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider" services="import"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" services="import"/>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>
```

After start `JBOSS` write in logs

> JBAS018759: Failed to load module: deployment.Astron-Service_Web.war:main
>       Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.skeleton-key:main"}}

How to fix. Or how to easy implement security on rest service?

Comment: Did you resolve this question??? I need to develop a REST service with oauth2 security. Now I'm using Restlet but is more difficult to use that Resteasy. So, maybe I'll change to Resteasy, but under Tomcat.

Comment: no. I stoped this task

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the module "org.jboss.resteasy.skeleton-key" in your jboss/wildfly server.

The module can be found in your downloaded resteasy project folder, in a zip named like "resteasy-jboss-modules-wfX-X.X.XX.Final.zip" for Wildfly. (There is also one for Jboss).

The github documentation of the project advice us to unzip the full folder under the module directory of our server (like wildfly-9.0.1.Final\modules).
Personnally I encountered severals new errors and have then just installed the "org\jboss\resteasy\skeleton-key" module. (maybe due to my wildfly 9.0 installation and modules in v8.0)

Links:

github project :
https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/tree/master/jaxrs/examples/oauth2-as7-example 
module installation : http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7